# Invoke class instance like function

Tags: typescript

In TypesScript, is it possible to define a class such that you could invoke a 'default' method as if the instance is a method name? Here's an example of what I mean.

```
export class StringBuilder {
  private inner = '';
  ...
  public ToString(): string {
    return inner;
  }
}
```

Then let's say in some calling code, I have an instance of the class and I want to call it this way:

```
const sb = new StringBuilder('xample');
sb(0, 'e');
console.log(sb.ToString()); // assume the logic adds the string at index 0, so should log 'example'
```

Is it possible to define a method that would accept those two arguments that would be invoked when using the instance itself like that?

It seems like a call signature is what I need, but I'm struggling to find examples that suit this scenario.

This is for a project where I'm handling some TypeScript code that is transcoded from legacy VB.NET code, so I'm trying to code to an implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
class Callable extends Function {
    private _bound;

    constructor() {
        super('...args', 'return this._bound.call(...args)');
        this._bound = this.bind(this)
        return this._bound
    }
}

class StringBuilder extends Callable {
    call(...args: any[]) {
        console.log(...args);
    }
}


const sb = new StringBuilder();
sb(0, 'e');
```

Comment: This definitely seems like it's working, thank you! I want to experiment a bit with this, but so far so good.